# cv2.imshow not implemented Mac python3 opencv3

Tags: macos, python-3.x, opencv3.0

I'm new to OpenCV and am having a problem with cv2.imshow.   Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

print("Version is", cv2.__version__)
print("Build info", cv2.getBuildInformation())
img = cv2.imread('../coelacanth.jpeg', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
if img is None: 
    print("no image")
else:
    print("there is an image")
cv2.line(img, (0,0), (150, 150), (255, 255, 255), 15)

cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I get this error:

```
line 16, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('image', img)
 line 16, in <module>
cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.error: /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:583: error: (-2) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function cvShowImage
```

The call to `cv2.line` seems to work.  If try `cv2.waitKey(0)` without the `imshow`, I get the same error.

I installed OpenCV3 with

```
brew install --with-examples --with-contrib --with-python3 --with-qt --without-python -v opencv3
```

So, clearly I need to

```
Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support
```

but I don't know how to do that and haven't been able to work that out from searching other questions.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: How did you install Python3?

Comment: I installed using `brew install python3`

Answer (score 1):

It was a pathing problem.   In `.bash_profile`, we commented out

```
#PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"
#export PATH
```

Then uninstalled with `brew uninstall opencv3`   and reinstalled with the brew command given in the original question.